# Is it possible to include php function inside AJAX success: val()

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Is it Possible to include php function inside JS/Ajax?  `$('#rb').val(response.uid);` `uid` is sql table and results are encrypted using custom php function can be decrypt using custom php function declared in php.

> data sent from get.php => `$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` `echo json_encode($result);`

Now Normally variables are decrypted as `decrypt($row['uid']);` how can decrypt `val(response.uid)`?

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'get.php',
    data: {id:id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
            $('#rb').val(response.uid); 
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You can return PHP data to JS, yes.

Comment: Either a) decrypt the information before sending it or b) decrypt it on the client side (using JS code, you cannot run PHP client-side)

Comment: yes but data is encrypted ... this will literally show encrypted data as text.

Comment: Okay the next question would be - why are you encrypting a user id?

Comment: Chris G working on that thanks.

Comment: Mark Overton uid is encrpted in another table for inner join

Comment: Yes, as @MarkOverton says, no problem to return PHP data from your database to JS via Ajax requests. Just keep in mind that your data might be personnal if it's regarding a specific user (as you are encrypting it). So don't forget to handle a session like you do for the HTML pages. If the user isn't logged in in the page then your Ajax backend PHP script should not return the sensitive data.

Comment: If your PHP is secure enough, you shouldn't need to encrypt any of the data you're returning, and obviously some data such as passwords should never be sent to the client.

Comment: its encrypted just because of no one can read information over sql table directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `data sent from get.php => $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
>
> `$result['uid'] = decrypt($result['uid']);`

`echo json_encode($result);`

Thanks Chris G For the push and i solved it on my own.
This is the simplest way to fix this.